# Can I query Changesets via tfpt.exe, tf.exe, or via the TFS API (from powershell)?

Tags: tfs, powershell, tfs-power-tools

I know how to query workitems, although I haven't been very successful finding info on the WIQL. There's one basic example that seems to get repeated everywhere.

I'd like to be able to query changesets.  Can I do it with tf.exe, tfpt.exe, or.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [October 2008 release of the TFS PowerTools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) has some cmdlets for working with change sets.

- Add-TfsPendingChange
- ConvertTo-FixedByte
- ConvertTo-FixedPath
- Get-TfsChangeset
- Get-TfsChildItem
- Get-TfsItemHistory
- Get-TfsItemProperty
- Get-TfsPendingChange
- Get-TfsServer
- Get-TfsShelveset
- Get-TfsWorkspace
- New-TfsChangeset
- New-TfsShelveset
- Remove-TfsPendingChange
- Remove-TfsShelveset
- Restore-TfsShelveset
- Select-TfsItem
- Set-TfsChangeset
- Update-TfsWorkspace

Answer (score 3):

Get-TfsItemHistory is probably the one you want.

```
NAME
    Get-TfsItemHistory

SYNTAX
    Get-TfsItemHistory [-HistoryItem] <QualifiedItemSpec> [-Prompt] [-Recurse] [-Server
<TeamFoundationServer>] [-Slotmode] [-Stopafter <String>] [-User <String>] [-Version <String>]
[-All] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Use the -All parameter if you want to enumerate the Changes collection inside each changeset.  Without -All the query is much faster, but only returns the changeset metadata.

See [my blog](http://richardberg.net/blog/?p=30) for an explanation of *QualifiedItemSpec*.

If you can't use Powershell for whatever reason, regular old [tf history](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx) can do almost everything Get-TfsItemHistory can.  It's just harder to compose into scripts.